# Uninstall Linux from dual boot and Install it again

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, boot, partitioning

Today, I installed Zorin os 16. Then to update python to latest version, I had to remove it and then update as per details provided by an online source. During that, when I opened settings, it said something like Gnome xxx failed no such commmand. So I fed up and decided to restart and it began showing like plymouth bin line 18 not found etc. So now I couldn't find any solution online. So I have decided to delete that linux and reinstall it. So do I have to remove the Linux Boot entry? Since I'm going to install again, is it okay to keep that old boot entry ? It would be helpful if someone could give step by step solution
Note : I did it dual boot with win 10 and I want to do the same after uninstalling linux.

Comment: Easiest is to restore from the last disk image. If you don't have one, then see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042746/reinstalling-ubuntu-with-a-dual-boot

Answer (score 0):

If you repeat the installation procedure of Zorin OS from the beginning as you did for the first installation, it should completely replace the system and replace the boot sector.
Just make sure that you select the same partitions for `root/` and `home/` and `swap/` when reinstalling otherwise you may accidentaly wipe out Windows as well.